# Question regarding proof of degree of minimal polynomial being $\le n^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently studying a proof regarding the minimal polynomial's degree, which states that it's less than or equal to $( n^2)$, where $( n )$ is the dimension of the vector space on which the operator acts. In the proof, it's mentioned:

*"The dimension of the transformations acting on $( V )$ is $( n^2 )$"*

I'm trying to understand why this statement holds true. Initially, I assumed the dimension would be $( n )$, since we represent transformations with $( n \times n )$ matrices. However, the statement suggests otherwise. Could someone please explain why the dimension of the space of transformations on $( V )$ is $( n^2 )$?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Regards,
Nomi.

Comment: How many entries are in an $n\times n$ matrix?

Comment: $n^2$ is correct for the dimension, but $n$ is a bound for the degree, by the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning behind "I assumed the dimension would be $(n)$, since we represent transformations with $(n \times n)$ matrices"

Comment: So a basis for the linear transformation L is then span([1, 0; 0, 0], [0, 1; 0, 0], [0, 0; 1, 0], [0, 0; 0, 1]), and so on for all n >= 1. 'Can you explain your reasoning' I suppose I had some confusion since I focus on the number of columns, which here isn't related as we have can have more linearly independent vectors than the number of columns in the matrix. Here the basis "vectors" are matrices... Thanks plp! "n is a bound for the degree" perhaps true but the proof I read sets a higher bound, setting it <= dim(L). youtube.com/watch?v=3WkxhuzcSCE Sheldon Axlers "Linear algebra done right"

Comment: Surely Axler proves, or at least states, the theorem bounding the degree of the minimal polynomial by $n$?

Comment: Maybe somewhere in the book, but at least in the video I linked the proof bounds it by n^2 using a list of length n^2 + 1 of which one power of T must be linearly dependent due to the length of the list of matrices being  > the dimension of all transformations on V, using the linear dependence lemma. And then he uses that dependency to construct n^2 as an upper bound on the degree of the minimal polynomial.